# Is this highlighted phrase acting as a complete sentence by implying something?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Here is the beginning of  a paragraph from *The Girl on the Train: A Novel* by Paula Hawkins. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=Udv-AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT9&dq=%22Beautiful+sunshine,+cloudless+skies.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjc1r-dxvbQAhVllFQKHQSfDYUQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Beautiful%20sunshine%2C%20cloudless%20skies.%22&f=false)):

> It’s going to be a lovely weekend, that’s what they’re telling
>   us. **Beautiful sunshine, cloudless skies**. In the old days we might
>   have driven to Corly Wood with a picnic and the papers, spent
>   all afternoon lying on a blanket in dappled sunlight, drinking
>   wine...

Can a phrase such as the one in bold really come between two complete sentences?

Comment: Define "complete sentence."

Comment: That is technically a malformed sentence, however most novels are stacked to the gills with them.  In novels, particularly with established writers, a lot more liberties can be taken, at least with the English language.

Comment: If you looked at a great work of art, and someone asked what you thought of it, would "Beautiful!" not be a perfectly valid response?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This form is used in literature for reported speech or for inner monologues.

It's an amplification of the previous sentence.

> It's going to be a lovely weekend...  (because it's going to have) beautiful sunshine (and) cloudless skies.